# How to clone aurelia / aureliajs app onto fresh windows 10?

Tags: node.js, npm, aurelia, node-gyp

Can someone please assist me in cloning aurelia / aureliajs app onto fresh windows 10 using JetBrains webstorm ?

**Steps I took:**

1. Install Windows 10
2. Install JDK
3. Install Python 2.7
4. Install Nodist
5. cmd: nodist latest command (to make sure)
6. go to site root folder
7. cmd: npm install npm -g
8. cmd: npm install jspm bower gulp -g
9. jspm registry config github
10. npm install && jspm install && bower install

(please note my app is using jspm/bower/graceful so, for those who don't use it, well.. please don't insert it)

Python is being used for NodeGyp.

Thanks
Anyone !?

Comment: what is the problem you're trying to solve? the steps above don't work? any error message?

Comment: grafeful js error appears after i run gulp watch, but that's at the complete end.  I'm only asking to make sure I haven't missed anything, that's all..

for example, in some cases, I had to edit the environment variables and edit other parameters related to system configurations on windows whereas, in others, I don't :(

Comment: I'm not sure about graceful, might be worth including a link to that library as it's not clear which one it is, do you need JDK and Python 2.7 for that?

Comment: nodegyp requires python on windows and jdk is being used for webstorm (sorry, im wrong here, rectifying... )